# Why cacheable="false" is not recommended on marketplace?

Tags: magento2, cache, block-cache

I have developed a custom module,

If my cache enables dynamic data pages are not on updating every request so I have added `cacheable="false"` now everything is working perfectly.
XML file : `view/frontend/layout/routerid_controller_action.xml`

But When I upload the extension on marketplace they are giving `cacheable="false"` error.

As per Magento's default documentation, if you add `cacheble=false` in some blocks full page cache mechanism not works. but my point is I have an entirely new page which almost has all the dynamic data then how they are telling for this error.

Also, I have checked the core modules 'module-sales','module-customer' they are also using `cacheable="false"` in their XML(s)?

I have also tried `isScopePrivate=true` but it's no longer supports
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3202#issuecomment-253496851

So Please let me know if there is an alternate solution.

Comment: In which layout file you are using this?

Comment: view/frontend/layout/routerid_controllername_action.xml

Comment: What is the layout handle bro? Is it default.xml?